# Excel macro - Split content of multiple rows into new rows and populates data from neighbouring columns

Tags: split

Splitting multiple cells with dynamic content into new rows

Hi All,
I am new to the forum. I would be much obliged for some help on the below.
I have a worksheet with a table in it, which contains data organised in multiple rows (sometimes 100) and around 2 columns. First column is consecutive number of the row, the second column keeps name of the data owner, third and following columns keep figures for the respective data owners. In some cases the column with the names, contains more than 1 name, names are always spearate by ";". Since data comes from outside, in some times in 2nd and 4th row contain more than one name, in other times, co-owners are in rows, 1, 3, 8 and sometimes there are no co-oweners in the entire table.

I need to split the data in the co-owned rows and put each of the co-woners in a new row.

Here is how the tables looks when the data arrives:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jane | 100 | 150 |
| 2 | Jane;John;Rich | 30 | 300 |
| 3 | John | 50 | 200 |
| 4 | John;Rich | 50 | 100 |
| 5 | Rich | 70 | 75 |

Here is how it should look like:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jane | 100 | 150 |
| 2 | Jane | 10 | 100 |
| 2 | John | 10 | 100 |
| 2 | Rich | 10 | 100 |
| 3 | John | 50 | 200 |
| 4 | John | 25 | 50 |
| 4 | Rich | 25 | 50 |
| 5 | Rich | 70 | 75 |